# Run ansible tasks based on machine names in a group

Tags: ansible

I want to create symlinks for a file using ansible only when I have a certain machine hostname.
I know `inventory_hostname` will give me the hostname, but can I do something like:
`when: inventory_hostname in group['machines']` so I can run this with all machines in that group?
Then, I want to symlink based on name of machine. So:

```
file:
    src: {{ ansible_hostname }}.png
    dest: anything.png
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You dont need the `when: inventory_hostname in group['machines']` condition at all.

You just have to run this task in a play towards `hosts: machines`, and you will have the symbolic link created to all hosts of the `machines` group.

**UPDATE**

if you still want to go for it, and run the playbook towards a `big_group` but only take action when host is part of the `small_group`, here is a play that can do it:

hosts file:

```
[big_group]
greenhat
localhost

[small_group]
localhost
```

playbook:

```
---
- hosts: big_group
  # connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars:

  tasks:
  - name: print if machine is eligible for symbolic
    debug:
      msg: "machine: {{ inventory_hostname }} is eligible for symbolic link!"
    when: inventory_hostname in groups['small_group']
```

result:

```
PLAY [big_group] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [print if machine is eligible for symbolic] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [greenhat]
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "machine: localhost is eligible for symbolic link!"
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
greenhat                   : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

hope it helps

Comment: I don't want to hardcode in which machines to use and which not to. I have 2 large groups of machines that I want to run this on. some to symlink and some not to, but I want to include this in a task that I need the other machines in hence the wish for the when condition

Comment: Thanks. This is what i needed. I have some unrelated problems, but those will only take a bit of debug time

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you have to use other groups to gather their facts. However, your tasks will run only against one group.
That time, you can use simply `"mygroup" in group_names`

`group_names` is a magic variable will be filled in automatically by groups of the current host.

e.g:

```yaml
- hosts: mygroup,othergroup
  tasks:
  - name: x
    when: 'mygroup' in group_names
```